# Connect Samsung S7 to Mac

Tags: android, samsung-mobile

Basically I'm trying to run my application on a Samsung S7 but my Mac isn't recognizing the device.  I've tried installing Android File Transfer and it doesn't recognize it either.  USB Debugging is enabled as well.  Any ideas?  The device OS is 6.0.1.

Comment: This is relevant to software development how?

Comment: I need to test my applications on the device

Comment: There is an [AndroidStackExchange](http://android.stackexchange.com/) that may be better suited for this question.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve this by doing the following:

1. Go to `Settings -> Quick Settings -> About device`
2. Tap on `Build number` 7 times.
3. Go to `Settings -> System -> Developer options -> USB Debugging`
4. Switch this option to `ON`.
5. Connect your device to your computer using a USB cable
6. Open Google Chrome
7. Visit `chrome://inspect`
8. Look at your device prompting you to allow your computer to communicate to your device via USB, and click `ALLOW`.

After that, you should see your device and be able to troubleshoot open browser tabs described here and click the `Inspect` button next to any open webpages to get all JavaScript console, Network tab, etc. that Google Chrome offers when debugging a webpage normally on desktop.